# Noob JavaScript Question - trying to assign a variable from a html text input and then have that variable used in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to assign a variable from a html text input value and then have that variable used in a function that uses the jquery ":contains" selector to hide divs that don't match the variable...here is the code I have...

```
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="Text/JavaScript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="Text/JavaScript">
var myform = document.forms[0];
var FilterText = myform.FilterText.value;

function FilterBlocks()
{
$("div.block").hide();
$("div.block:contains(FilterText)").show();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="#">
<input class="navButtons" type="text" name="FilterText">
<input class="navButtons" type="button" name="FilterButton" value="Filter Videos"     onMouseUp="FilterBlocks()">
<br /><br />
</form>
<div class="block"><a href="1.html"><img src="images/1.jpg">This is the title<a></div>
</body>
```

I tried doing an alert() with the variable that I an trying to use but it's coming back undefined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to do it this way,

```
function FilterBlocks(){
   $("div.block").hide();
   $("div.block:contains("+FilterText+")").show();
}
```

and also, calling `var myform = document.forms[0];`, in your code above, would result `myform` as `undefined` because `DOM` is not yet ready.

you might want it this way,

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="Text/JavaScript">
$(function(){
   // call it when DOM is ready
   var myform = document.forms[0];
   var FilterText = myform.FilterText.value;

   function FilterBlocks(){
     $("div.block").hide();
     $("div.block:contains("+FilterText+")").show();
   }
});
</script>
```

for better jQuery style codes, I suggest this,

```
<input class="navButtons" type="button" name="FilterButton" value="Filter Videos"     onMouseUp="FilterBlocks()">
```

to just,

```
<input class="navButtons" type="button" name="FilterButton" value="Filter Videos" >
```

your jQuery would be,

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="Text/JavaScript">
$(function(){
   // call it when DOM is ready
   var myform = document.forms[0];

   $('.navButtons:button').click(function(){
     var FilterText = myform.FilterText.value;
     $("div.block").hide();
     $("div.block:contains("+FilterText+")").show();
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help...your last cleaned up jQuery seems to wok great! alot to take in for a beginner but I will enjoy dissecting it...

Answer (score 2):

Try `$("div.block:contains(" + FilterText + ")").show();` instead. You'll need to 'escape' special characters too (`(`, `)`, etc), but this should work on simple strings.

And BTW, what you are coding in called Javascript, not Java.

Comment: Thanks for the help...

and so that I'm clear...Java is the program and what I'm writing is the Javascript...right?

Thanks!

Comment: @user430264 - No, Java and javascript doesn't have any connection at all. they are 2 different language with some few similarities.